# mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in directory name

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

i have facing problem in php code. the error is given below:

```
mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in directory name
```

the php code is:

```
<?php
$edit_record = $_GET['edit'];

$query = "select * from std_reg where student_id='edit_record'";

$run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run))
{
$id = $row['Student_id'];
$name = $row['name'];
}
?>
```

can any one help?

Comment: change to `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run))`

Comment: still not working yara

Comment: your query `"select * from std_reg where student_id='$edit_record'";`

Comment: `$run` is a `boolean` because your query failed. Add some error checking before you enter the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the result type to `mysqli_fetch_array`.

See the [syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp): `mysqli_fetch_array(result,resulttype);`

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
```

Comment: No you don't. The second parameter has a default value.

Answer (score 1):

1. `$row` is not defined anywhere. In `while` loop you must set `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)`.
2. You are not passing value to query correctly. `$` is missing here `student_id='edit_record'`.

   ```
   <?php
   $edit_record = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['edit']);

   $query = "SELECT * FROM std_reg WHERE student_id='$edit_record'";

   $run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);


   if($run)
   {
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run))
       {
           $id = $row['Student_id'];
           $name = $row['name'];
       }
   }
   ?>
   ```

Comment: @ImranKhan I have updated my answer. `$` is missing here `student_id='edit_record'`

Comment: @ImranKhan does my answers works for you?

Answer (score 1):

Give row name to while loop and add `$` to edit_record in query

```
$edit_record = $_GET['edit'];

$query = "select * from std_reg where student_id='$edit_record'";

$run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run))
{
  $id = $row['Student_id'];
  $name = $row['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` rather than `mysqli_fetch_array`. It gives you the result you wanted without having to explicitly say what type of array you wanted.

Comment: You should give an example and maybe link to the documentation to improve your answer.

Answer (score -2):

From this query:

```
$query = "select * from std_reg where student_id='edit_record'";
```

To this query:

```
<?php
$edit_record = $_GET['edit'];$query = "select * from std_reg where student_id=".$edit_record; //Please try to observed the concatenation

$run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)) {
$id = $row['Student_id'];
$name = $row['name'];
}
?>
```

Comment: I've edited my answer now.

Comment: You should add an explanation of what/why this works, and the original doesn't...